# pipe specific list of gziped log files into zgrep

Tags: linux, find, grep, logging

I'm having trouble with getting a list of the lines in a bunch of gzipped apache access log files.  What I want is to get a list of the log files numbered 1 and 2 only, then grep through them and extract the lines with specific matching text.

I originally got this to work just for access log archives numbered 1.  The "/pathname" text was the text I was looking for:

```
zgrep /pathname/ access_*.log.1.gz
```

Since ls does not support regex, I came up with the following to get a listing from the current directory of the files I want:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '\./access.+\.log\.[1|2]\.gz' -printf '%P\n'

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '\./access.+\.log\.[1|2]\.gz' | sed "s|^\./||"
```

My problem now is taking that file list output and zgrepping through the files to return lines within those files that match my text.  Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
zgrep /pathname/ access_*.log.{1,2}.gz
```

Alternatively, use find -exec:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '\./access.+\.log\.[1|2]\.gz' -exec zgrep /path/ {} \;
```

Comment: Dammit.  The answer, when dealing with linux, is always easier than you'd imagine.  That worked just fine, dogbane.  Thank you muchly!

Comment: I used the first one, by and by.  I tried the second command (with exec) and that worked too.  Thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have apache-logs, so I use a similar, but not identical pattern:

```
ls /var/log/*.[12].gz
```

The shell doesn't support regex, but grouping with [123] or [1-3], as well as {1,2,3} and {1..3} or even {o..w} and {066..091}.